# Using JavaScript template with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, templates

I ran into this problem multiple times in my career, and never was able to find a elegant solution for it. Imagine you have a simple page, that has a repeater. You populate that repeater on the server-side through the databinding. That's great, works fast and does what it's supposed to. But now you want to add paginator to that repeater, or otherwise change the output. Doing it through Ajax is a preferred way to enable rich client interaction.

So you create a web-service that serves you the data as JSON, but now you are stuck... Either you have to write complicated client-side code to find each field that you need to modify in each repeater-item, or you have to blow away the whole server-side output of the repeater and construct new HTML from the scratch, or, the method that I've been using lately, take the first repeated item, blow away everything else and clone the first item as many time as you need to and modify it's fields.

All of the described methods are not optimal, because no matter what, they require quite a bit of repeated logic on the server-side (i.e. template in repeater) and on the client-side (javascript to display JSON data). There's got to be a better, easier way to do this. First thing that comes to mind, is instead of returning JSON from the web-server, return HTML of the pre-populated repeater. But for something like that, I might as well use ASP.NET AJAX Update panel. The output isn't going to be any smaller with a stand-alone web-service.

Next thing that I thought of, is JavaScript templates. What if there would be some way to take unprocessed repeater template on the server-side, and convert it to JavaScript template that could be either embedded on the page at load, or served as part of the web-service response. However, I couldn't find any existing solutions for something like this. And I can't think of a simple way to do that myself. Any ideas?

P.S. Rendering JavaScript template to the client-side on page load, and using JavaScript to populate it without the initial view being rendered on the server (no repeater and databinding) is out of the question. I care too much about performance.

Comment: How is your performance going to be worse if you offload the templating to the client? That's literally going to be the best solution.

Comment: Not at all. If you databind on the server for the initial page load, you are serving back pure HTML. If you serve back a javascript template and JSON (either as part of the page, or, god forbid as an AJAX request), you not only need to serve pure HTML, you also have to process it with JavaScript after the page is done loading. Initial load of the page should always be fully rendered on the server, since it's a controlled environment.

Comment: Many well trafficked sites like gmail would disagree.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they wouldn't disagree. There's not much to disagree about here. If your server is not handling the load, it's easy, just upgrade your server, get more memory and better CPU, add more nodes to the farm. You are in control. If you clients, however, are using IE6 on Pentium I machines, while running video processing on the background, you can't do anything about that at all... So I don't think Google would disagree, I think they are just trying to cut the costs of the development to a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about all pros and cons of different approaches, I stopped on the following method. I created a custom ASP.NET databound control, that can render HTML, however, when the page is requested with query string parameters, instead of just doing standard rendering, it will use Response.Clear() and Response.End() and in between of those two commands output JSON version of data based on the query string parameters. Also on the first rendering of the page, it will also output JavaScript template using reflections to read names of the variables from the control's template area.

This method works great, all I have to do, is drop my control on the page, data bind it, and it works as a true AJAX grid that supports pagination, sorting and filtering. However it does have limitation. In the control's template you can only specify variables, not expressions. Otherwise reflections can't convert it to a JavaScript variable. But I can live with that.

Other possibilities that I considered is a separate web-service that takes a type of the page as parameter and uses reflection to get data bound object as well as create template for the grid. I also though about writting my own version of update panel, that would not use view state and only send in part of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't believe that using client template with JSON data even on first load will adversely affect the performance unless we are talking about devices with different form factors such as phones etc.

However, if you must use server side templating/rendering then why not make server return the html for the repeater. This can be done by putting repeater logic into a different user control/page and processing only that page on ajax request. And this is not at all equivalent to using UpdatePanel (as stated by you) - UpdatePanel posts entire page data (including view-state) having more request size. The response size is also larges because it must contain the view-state. On server side also, use of UpdatePanel results in loading complete control tree with state data and post-back event processing. Sending only the requisite html is much better approach and will fit your needs perfectly - only issue is the html would be larger in size as compared to JSON.

Lastly, there are some interesting projects such as [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) - Script# converts C# code into java-script. You may build something similar (using script# itself) to convert the server side templating code into eqivalent JS code. More viable approach on similar lines could be use T4 templating to convert a technology-agnostic template into both server side code (markup + code or pure code) and equivalent JS-code.

Comment: If we are talking about an example that I gave - true, performance isn't going to suffer much. But a real life example, of a large page with a multiple databound areas, or one very large, multi-variable area that is databound, it's probably going to be noticeable. Agree on UpdatePanels, I just has been turning off view-state on my pages for such a long time, I forgot about it:-) Good idea on Script#. I'll take a look, and T4 templates, in theory sounds good, but in practice, I think is going to be more trouble then it's worth.

Comment: @Ilya, I have pointed Script# for conceptual perspective. IMO, it would be take more efforts to use that for this specific need or build something like that. I still believe that using some custom template engine such as T4 is doable and offer more flexibility.